# Reusing a phone number in two (or more) Facebook accounts - Is it allowed?

Tags: facebook, account-management, security, phone-number

I have two Facebook accounts for some personal reasons. I have my phone number registered to one of them. I want to register my phone number to also the other one for security reason, but I'm worried for fact that Facebook does not allow multiple accounts.

My question is, will Facebook ban one or both of my accounts if I reuse my phone number in a second account?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use the same phone number or address in your contact information. However, you can't [verify multiple accounts with the same number](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=187931727930637#Why-can%27t-I-use-my-phone-number-to-verify-multiple-accounts?).